# Facebook login occasionally return empty JSON

Tags: android, facebook, parsing

I've integrated Facebook SSO with my Android app, and I'd say about 80-85% of the time it works fine. But every once in a while, it returns an empty JSON, and I'm not sure why. I'm using [Parse](https://parse.com/) to integrate with Facebook, and here's the code:

```
ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(mContext, new LogInCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException ex) {
        if (user != null) {
            //login successful
        } else if (ex != null) {
            ex.printStackTract();
            //something failed
        }
    }
});
```

This logIn() method is basically a wrapper of Facebook.authorize() that sends the result through to Parse's own callback, with any exceptions wrapped in a ParseException. When it fails, it gives me a JSONException:

```
08-06 14:53:16.706: W/System.err(13996): com.parse.ParseException: org.json.JSONException: End  of input at character 0 of 
08-06 14:53:16.721: W/System.err(13996):    at com.parse.ParseUser$8.onError(ParseUser.java:944)
08-06 14:53:16.721: W/System.err(13996):    at com.parse.auth.FacebookAuthenticationProvider.handleError(FacebookAuthenticationProvider.java:189)
08-06 14:53:16.721: W/System.err(13996):    at com.parse.auth.FacebookAuthenticationProvider.access$1(FacebookAuthenticationProvider.java:185)
08-06 14:53:16.721: W/System.err(13996):    at com.parse.auth.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$GetUserIdBackgroundTask.onPostExecute(FacebookAuthenticationProvider.java:49)
08-06 14:53:16.721: W/System.err(13996):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
08-06 14:53:16.721: W/System.err(13996):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
08-06 14:53:16.721: W/System.err(13996):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
08-06 14:53:16.725: W/System.err(13996):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-06 14:53:16.725: W/System.err(13996):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-06 14:53:16.725: W/System.err(13996):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-06 14:53:16.733: W/System.err(13996):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 14:53:16.733: W/System.err(13996):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-06 14:53:16.733: W/System.err(13996):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
08-06 14:53:16.737: W/System.err(13996):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
08-06 14:53:16.737: W/System.err(13996):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-06 14:53:16.737: W/System.err(13996): Caused by: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
08-06 14:53:16.757: W/System.err(13996):    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:446)
08-06 14:53:16.757: W/System.err(13996):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:93)
08-06 14:53:16.757: W/System.err(13996):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
08-06 14:53:16.757: W/System.err(13996):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
08-06 14:53:16.757: W/System.err(13996):    at com.parse.auth.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$GetUserIdBackgroundTask.doInBackground(FacebookAuthenticationProvider.java:38)
08-06 14:53:16.757: W/System.err(13996):    at com.parse.auth.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$GetUserIdBackgroundTask.doInBackground(FacebookAuthenticationProvider.java:1)
08-06 14:53:16.761: W/System.err(13996):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-06 14:53:16.761: W/System.err(13996):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun (FutureTask.java:305)
08-06 14:53:16.761: W/System.err(13996):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-06 14:53:16.764: W/System.err(13996):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
08-06 14:53:16.764: W/System.err(13996):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
08-06 14:53:16.764: W/System.err(13996):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Usually if I just try to login again immediately afterwards, it will work. Since it's so inconsistent, I'm really at a loss as to what could be causing it. Is this something that just happens with Facebook, or is Parse the more likely culprit?

On a possibly related note, I will also intermittently get IOExceptions due to either timeouts or broken pipes doing the same thing. These will usually recur for a few tries, and then it will work again. Like I said, these errors are infrequent, but they happen often enough to make me think that Facebook's servers can't be that unreliable and something else might be going on.

Anyone else experience something similar, especially Parse users?

**EDIT:** So the same exact errors are popping up when I try to get a list of the user's friends through Facebook.request():

```
String friends = ParseFacebookUtils.getFacebook().request("me/friends");
JSONObject result = Util.parseJson(friends);
```

Parse contains a full copy of the Facebook SDK so this method is just the standard unadulterated call throught the Facebook instance. It works 9 times out of 10, but again, the same periodic JSONException is thrown on parseJson();

Answer (score 0):

I'd contact Parse support and ask them what can be wrong. From my experience of extensive usage of Facebook Android SDK I've never seen such error. As a wild guess the may be incorrectly treating OnError callback as a regular one and trying to parse the response as JSON while it's it's in plain text for example.

What prevents you from using raw Facebook SDK? It's pretty straightforward

Comment: I was starting to think that, but now I've actually found that I'll get the same periodic errors when getting a friends list through Facebook.request(). This method isn't wrapped by the Parse API, so if you've never seen these errors, I think it must be something I'm doing. I'll post the code in an edit.

Comment: As for your question, mainly because I'm already using Parse for other functionalities and it provides a nice way to handle Facebook user data in the context of my own users system. Other than these infrequent errors, it really does work quite nicely so I'd like to use it if possible.